# Spacing between listview items of a single row

Tags: android, android-listview

A single row in my listview contains of an image and text. I want to add space in between this text and image which are placed beside each other. How can i do this?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="" />
```

I am using this.

Comment: What you try? post it

Comment: You need to tell us what kind of adapter you are using to populate the list view.

Comment: Also post the layout of the row.

Comment: There are different ways, either give padding to text, margin or simply add a view in between those two and it will work as a space between them `<View android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="2dp"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the layout margin attribute to the view.

See: [MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#lattrs)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/dat_img"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/dat_good_words"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:text="Dat GooooD Words" />

</LinearLayout>
```